# RemoveEventListener do not work in Firefox ver 58

Tags: javascript, firefox

but it works in Chrome.

Here is my code from UI_EventBus (prototype):
(The addEventListener method is the same, but the remove is replaced with add.)

```
UI_EventBus.removeEventListener = function(obj, argEventType, argEventHandler) {
    var element;;
    var strObj = obj.toString();

    if(strObj.indexOf("HTML") > -1) 
        element = obj;
    else
        element = obj.getElement();


    element.removeEventListener(argEventType, function(event){
        argEventHandler(event,obj);
    });

}
```

I call this from UI_Event (prototype):

```
closeDragElement:   function(event, obj) {
event = event || window.event;
UI_EventBus.removeEventListener(obj,"mouseup", obj.closeDragElement);
UI_EventBus.removeEventListener(document,"mouseup", obj.closeDragElement);
UI_EventBus.removeEventListener(obj,"mousemove", obj.elementDrag);
}
```

I've added it from this method in UI_Event (prototype) :

```
dragMouseDown:   function(event, obj) {
event = event || window.event;

UI_EventBus.removeEventListener(obj,"mousedown", obj.dragMouseDown,[]);
obj.mouseX = event.clientX;
obj.mouseY = event.clientY;
UI_EventBus.addEventListener(obj,"mouseup", obj.closeDragElement);
UI_EventBus.addEventListener(document,"mouseup", obj.closeDragElement);
UI_EventBus.addEventListener(obj,"mousemove", obj.elementDrag);
}
```

I call the dragMouseDown -handler from UI_EventTest.html :

```
<script>
....
UI_EventBus.addEventListener(elem,"mousedown", elem.dragMouseDown);
..... 
</script>
```

---

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, to no avail. I really appreciate if someone could tell med what is wrong. The solution works in Chrome.

Comment: The argument passed to `.removeEventListener()` should be a function reference instead of an anonymous function

Comment: You are absolutly right! I did not think about it until know.
then I have to try to find a solution to this. 
But, why do it work in Chrome ?

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets or plnkr https://plnkr.co demonstrating `.removeEventListener()` removing the event handler where the handler is an anonymous function?

Comment: I didn't really understand your wish, but I've put out my new code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `removeEventListener` must be the function you want to remove.

You've put a function expression there, which will create a brand new function. As it is brand new, it can't have been previously added as an event listener.

Comment: Thank you very much Quentin. After having made new code based upon your answer, it eventually works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated code, if someone is interested in the solution:

UI_EventBus.listeners = [];

/*
  *   ADD EVENT LISTENER
  */

```
UI_EventBus.addEventListener = function(target,  argEventType, obj, argEventHandler) {
    var element;;
    var strObj = target.toString();

    if(strObj.indexOf("HTML") > -1) 
        element = target;
    else
        element = target.getElement();




    var func = function(event){ 
        argEventHandler(event,obj); 
    };
    //console.log(" Add : " + target + "  " +  argEventType + " " + obj + " " +  argEventHandler + " " + func + " no of listeners " + UI_EventBus.listeners.length);

    element.addEventListener(argEventType,func);

    var listener = [target,argEventType, obj, argEventHandler, func];



    UI_EventBus.listeners.push(listener);


}
/*
 *   REMOVE EVENT LISTENER
 */

UI_EventBus.removeEventListener = function(target, argEventType, obj, argEventHandler) {
    var element;;
    var strObj = target.toString();

    if(strObj.indexOf("HTML") > -1) 
        element = target;
    else
        element = target.getElement();



    var idx;
    var func;
    for(var i=0; i < UI_EventBus.listeners.length;i++)
        if(UI_EventBus.listeners[i][0] == target)
            //console.log("Obj " + UI_EventBus.listeners[i][0]);
            if(UI_EventBus.listeners[i][1] == argEventType)
                //console.log("Eventtype " + UI_EventBus.listeners[i][1]);
                if(UI_EventBus.listeners[i][2] == obj)
                    if(UI_EventBus.listeners[i][3] == argEventHandler){
                        //console.log("Handler " + UI_EventBus.listeners[i][2]);    
                        func =  UI_EventBus.listeners[i][4];
                        idx = i;
                        break;
                    }


    element.removeEventListener(argEventType,func);


    //console.log("no of listeners " + UI_EventBus.listeners.length + " idx=" + idx);
    //console.log(" Remove : " + UI_EventBus.listeners[i][0] + "  " +  UI_EventBus.listeners[i][1] + " " + UI_EventBus.listeners[i][2] + " " +  UI_EventBus.listeners[i][3] + " " +  UI_EventBus.listeners[i][4] );
    UI_EventBus.listeners.splice(idx,1);


}
```